# Why does this AJAX request fail before it begins?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

```
$.ajax("changeposition.aspx?id=1&pos=1", {
        success: function(){
          alert('success!');
       }
});
```

In chrome that code gives an error saying (failed) in the status code and undefined in the type column. The request does not reach the page as I've tried debugging but the page load event never fires. Any ideas? I am developing on localhost and this page is within an authenticated admin area.

UPDATE: screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Are you running an adblocker? Disable it.

Comment: Is this only happening in Chrome? If so, it probably has to do with a security restriction when accessing the page via `localhost`, and can be avoided by launching Chrome with the flag `--disable-web-security`.

Comment: @Quentin Add that as an answer and I'll accept, you are right, good thinking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some adblockers do keyword matching in JavaScript URIs. `banners.js` or some other factor may be triggering it.

Disable adblocking to test this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        url : "changeposition.aspx?id=1&pos=1",
        success: function(){
          alert('success!');
       }
});
```

Comment: pretty sure my syntax is fine, as per the docs. tried this way and same problem

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `$.ajax("/changeposition.aspx?id=1&pos=1", { ...` ?

(with the forward slash)

Comment: Only if the page is in the root and not the folder that the current executing file is in.